# Rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock game in gui python

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, game-physics

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class Application(Frame):
    """A Gui Application for a game."""
    def __init__(self,master):
        """Initialize the frame."""
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.wins = 0
        self.losses = 0
        self.ties = 0

    def computerRandom(self):
        options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Lizard", "Spock"]
        randomChoice = random.randint(0,4)


    def comparison(self, selfComputer): 
        if self.playerChoice.get()== selfComputer:
            return "Draw"
        elif self.playerChoice.get() == "Rock" and selfComputer == "Paper":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Paper" and selfComputer == "Scissors":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Scissors" and selfComputer == "Rock":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Lizard" and selfComputer == "Rock":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Lizard" and selfComputer == "Scissors":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Paper" and selfComputer == "Lizard":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Scissors" and selfComputer == "Spock":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Spock" and selfComputer == "Lizard":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Spock" and selfComputer == "Paper":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Rock" and selfComputer == "Spock":
            return "Computer Wins"
        else:
            return "Human Wins"



    def play(self):
        selfComputer = self.computerRandom() 
        result = self.comparison(selfComputer) 
        if result == "Draw":
            self.results_txt ="Its a draw"
        elif result == "Computer Wins":
            self.results_txt = "Unlucky you lost!"
        else:
            self.results_txt ="Well done you won!"


    def create_widgets(self):
        """Create labels and buttons."""
        #create welcome label
        Label(self,text = "Welcome to the Rock, Paper, Scissors, Spock and Lizard Game\n"
              "You chose one of the weapons to fight with and let's see if the computer\n"
              "beats you or not!! Enjoy!!").grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=3, sticky = W)

        #create difficulty label
        Label(self,text = "Which difficulty level would you like to play?:").grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)


        #create variables
        self.difficulty = StringVar()
        self.difficulty.set(None)
        self.playerChoice = StringVar()
        self.playerChoice.set(None)
        self.results = StringVar()
        self.computer_lbl = BooleanVar()
        self.computer_lbl.set(None)


        #radio buttons for difficulty levels
        Radiobutton(self,text = "Easy",variable = self.difficulty,value = "easy").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        Radiobutton(self,text = "Hard",variable = self.difficulty,value = "hard").grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = E)
        Label(self,text = " ").grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)

        #computer
        self.computer_lbl = Label(self, text = "Computer")
        self.computer_lbl.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.computer_lbl = Label(self,text = "[]Rock").grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.computer_lbl = Label(self,text = "[]Paper").grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.computer_lbl = Label(self,text = "[]Scissors").grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.computer_lbl = Label(self,text = "[]Lizard").grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.computer_lbl = Label(self,text = "[]Spock").grid(row = 9, column = 0, sticky = W)

        #player
        self.player_lbl = Label(self, text = "Player")
        self.player_lbl.grid(row = 4, column = 3, sticky = W)

        Radiobutton(self, text ="Rock",variable = self.playerChoice, value = "Rock").grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(self, text ="Paper",variable = self.playerChoice, value = "Paper").grid(row=6, column=3, sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(self, text ="Scissors",variable = self.playerChoice, value = "Scissors").grid(row=7, column=3, sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(self, text ="Lizard",variable = self.playerChoice, value = "Lizard").grid(row=8, column=3, sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(self, text ="Spock",variable = self.playerChoice, value = "Spock").grid(row=9, column=3, sticky=W)


        #buttons
        Label(self,text = " ").grid(row = 10, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.bttn2 = Button(self, text = "Fight!", command = self.play)
        self.bttn2.grid(row=11, column=3, sticky=W)

        self.play_bttn = Button(self,text = "Play!")
        self.play_bttn.grid(row=12, column=3, sticky=W)

        self.bttn3 = Button(self, text = "Exit", command = root.destroy)
        self.bttn3.grid(row=13,column=3, sticky=W)

        #Wins,Losses,Ties, and Results
        Label(self, text = "Results:").grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.results_txt = Text(self, width=30, height=5, wrap=WORD)
        self.results_txt.grid(row=5, rowspan=5, column=1, columnspan=1)




        self.wins_lbl = Label(self, text = "Wins:")
        self.wins_lbl.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.losses_lbl = Label(self, text = "Losses:")
        self.losses_lbl.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.ties_lbl = Label(self, text = "Ties:")
        self.ties_lbl.grid(row=13, column=0, sticky=W)





#main
root = Tk()
root.title("Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, and Spock ")
root.geometry("465x410")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I need it to keep score and to play period. Easy need to only enable rock, paper, and scissors, while hard does all of it. Then display the results in the text box. I've been trying over and over to get it to work but I am new to Python and need a little guidance. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show us the full traceback of the error, it will be easier to see what line is causing the issue.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python31\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Rock, paper,scissors.py", line 49, in play
    selfPlayer = playerChoice.get()
NameError: global name 'playerChoice' is not defined

Comment: `playerChoice` is a local name *only* in `create_widgets`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `self.playerChoice = StringVar()` to make it an attribute.

`self.results_txt("Well done you won!")` is a string so it is not callable.

Use `self.results_txt ="Well done you won!"`

You need to refer to `computerRandom()` as `self.computerRandom()`, it is a method of the class

`self.computer.set(options[randomChoice])` won't work as there is no `computer` attribute in your class.

Using `comparison(self, selfComputer)` would be better practice.

Also `result = comparison(self, selfComputer)` will again not work. Use `self.comparison`, it is a method also.

This code should be closer to what you need, I am not sure what `self.computer.set(options[randomChoice])` is supposed to be doing, that will have to be fixed.

```
from tkinter import *

import random
class Application(Frame):
    """A Gui Application for a game."""
    def __init__(self,master):
        """Initialize the frame."""
        super().__init__() 
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.wins = 0
        self.losses = 0
        self.ties = 0

    def computerRandom(self):
        options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Lizard", "Spock"]
        randomChoice = random.randint(0,4)
        self.computer.set(options[randomChoice])
        return options[randomChoice]

    def comparison(self, selfComputer): # use self as the first parameter, it refers to each instance 
         # use if/elif, eilf's will only be evaluated if the previous statement is False
        if self.playerChoice.get()== selfComputer:
            return "Draw"
        elif self.playerChoice.get() == "Rock" and selfComputer == "Paper":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Paper" and selfComputer == "Scissors":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Scissors" and selfComputer == "Rock":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Lizard" and selfComputer == "Rock":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Lizard" and selfComputer == "Scissors":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Paper" and selfComputer == "Lizard":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Scissors" and selfComputer == "Spock":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Spock" and selfComputer == "Lizard":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Spock" and selfComputer == "Paper":
            return "Computer Wins"
        elif self.playerChoice.get()== "Rock" and selfComputer == "Spock":
            return "Computer Wins"
        else:
            return "Human Wins"



    def play(self):
        selfComputer = self.computerRandom() # again we need to call a method using self

        result = self.comparison(selfComputer) # comparing self to `selfComputer`
        if result == "Draw":
            self.results_txt ="Its a draw"
        elif result == "Computer Wins":
            self.results_txt = "Unlucky you lost!"
        else:
            self.results_txt ="Well done you won!"


    def create_widgets(self):
        """Create labels and buttons."""
        #create welcome label
        Label(self,text = "Welcome to the Rock, Paper, Scissors, Spock and Lizard Game\n"
              "You chose one of the weapons to fight with and let's see if the computer\n"
              "beats you or not!! Enjoy!!").grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=3, sticky = W)

        #create difficulty label
        Label(self,text = "Which difficulty level would you like to play?:").grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)


        #create variables
        self.playerChoice = StringVar()
        self.playerChoice.set(None)
        self.results = StringVar()
```

Comment: Do you think you can edit the code and show me within it what to do? I see what you're trying to tell me but the more I fix it, the more errors I get

Comment: I am in the middle of doing that, can you explain what self.computer is supposes to be?

Comment: My labels are supposed to interact randomly as the player chooses his weapon. It probably would've worked better with radiobuttons but I chose labels instead. I'm a beginner to programming. Python is my first language. I was trying to work the program one step at a time. Get it to playing and then go with the difficulty levels.

Comment: Are you not able to randomly call a label @Padraic

Comment: you cannot call a string if that is what you mean, self.computer does not exist but all you have to do is update the label with the random choice, I am not totally sure what label you are trying to update

Comment: self.computer_lbl = Label(self,text = "[]Rock").grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)...These are the group of labels I'm trying to update

Comment: Is there anyway I can contact you through email or anything to fully explain to you what I'm trying to do? @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: I will update the answer with a few examples of how to update the labels when I get back on my laptop latet